# scraping multiple images using beautiful soup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab all of the img links in the slideshow on a Reuters article. I was wondering if someone could explain to me why this only grabs the first image and no others?

Here's the article for reference: http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/04/11/us-cocoa-gold-westafrica-insight-idUSBREA3A0DP20140411

```
links = soup.find_all("div", {'id': 'frame_fd1fade'})
for link in links:
    for img in link.find_all('img', src=True):
        img = img["src"].split("src=")[-1]
        print img
```

Answer (score 0):

In the page source for the article, there's only one `div` with `id="frame_fd1fade"`. Within it, there is one `img` tag, which contains the first picture. You'll have to look into the mechanism that the page uses to change pictures and use that somehow to get your images.

Try running this to see how many instances of `frame_fd1fade` there are in the source:

```
import urllib
import re

f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/04/11/us-cocoa-gold-westafrica-insight-idUSBREA3A0DP20140411")
cnt = 0
for line in f:
  if re.search("frame_fd1fade", line):
    cnt += 1
print "cnt =", cnt
```

Comment: In the page source all of the img's look like they are there. There is a separate div for each one. All of them are div id="frame_fd1fade" with a different corresponding image.

Comment: @user3285763, That's not what I see. Try the little program I added to my answer above. What count do you get?

Comment: Hmm well thanks for taking the time to do that. It does explain why I'm only getting one img source returned. I am a bit confused about what I am looking at then. In firefox inspect element there is a list of div id="frame_fd1fade". Each with the separate img file in it. They are each labeled div id="ic0", ic1, ic2, ic3, etc. This is all under div id="displayFrame". I am considering using regex but I wanted to try and avoid it.